# Open source SQL database with BASE semantics?

Tags: database, sql, nosql

Basically I'm looking for an Open-Source (or free) RDBMS with a SQL-like interface that is highly concurrent.

Some features I'm looking for:

- A rigid schema defined at "compile-time"
- A production-ready database that I can run on my laptop (No Bigtable, Aurora, etc; no trial versions)
- Highly concurrent reads and writes.
- Clusterable.
- A JDBC-compatible interface.
- BASE semantics, including eventual consistency.
- (optional) Support for constraints, including foreign keys
- (optional) Explicit indexes (simple or compound)

I'm also open to a plain-old RDBMS that can be configured to achieve BASE semantics.

Comment: Can you provide some details about BASE ?

Comment: BASE really means eventual consistency https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency